# Primefaces In cell editing data table event.getNewValue() sends the old value to the bean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to use the feature of prime faces which allows user to edit the cell data in the table itself.I have followed this link to achieve it:
[Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableCellEditing.jsf)

When I say edit a cell in the table, new values which are entered are not sent to the bean.It still shows the old values only.

My code JSF:

```
<h:form id="testform">            
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />  
 <p:outputPanel id="testContainer" deferred="true">          




   <p:remoteCommand name="oncompleteCellEdit" update="cars messages" />

   <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{articlesbean.LMatpilotaccess1}" editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="carsTable" update=":cars">  

       <f:facet name="header">  
            Matériel du pilotage et accessoires 
        </f:facet>  

   <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{articlesbean.onCellEdit}"   oncomplete="oncompleteCellEdit()"    update=":testform:messages" />

        <p:column headerText="Serie" style="width:25%">                

               <p:cellEditor >  
                   <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.serie}" /></f:facet>  
                   <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput16" value="#{car.serie}" style="width:96%"/></f:facet>  
               </p:cellEditor>  
         </p:column>  


   <p:column headerText="Cap" style="width:25%">                

               <p:cellEditor >  
                   <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.cap}" /></f:facet>  
                   <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput15" value="#{car.cap}" style="width:96%"/></f:facet>  
               </p:cellEditor>  
         </p:column> 

    </p:dataTable>  

 </p:outputPanel> 

    </h:form>
```

My code bean

```
    @ManagedBean(name="articlesbean")

    @ViewScoped
    public class ArticlesBean implements Serializable{

        @Inject
        private ArticlesDAO articleDAO;
        private Matpilotaccess1 matpilotaccess1;

    public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {  
          Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();  
           Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

           System.out.println("/////"+(event.getNewValue());
           System.out.println("/////"+(event.getOldValue());

         FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
          Matpilotaccess1 mpltiacc  = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{mpltiacc}", Matpilotaccess1.class);
          articleDAO.Updatetable(mpltiacc);
              }
/////////Getters and Setters
    }
```

and as result of

```
System.out.println("/////"+(event.getNewValue());
System.out.println("/////"+(event.getOldValue());
```

i got in both case the old value!!!

Could anyone let me know how I can get the new values???I am using Jboss 7 and primefaces4 Thanks

Comment: Is LMatpilotaccess1 a list? I know it was 2 years ago, but I found this question by chance.

Answer (score -3):

You need to annotate your bean with @SessionScoped annotation.